# Sharing code between node.js and Angular 2 breaks angular cli build

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

So we just began destructuring our backend app into smaller modules and came to this issue with `angular/cli`.

I have a couple of npm modules, of which one hold the interfaces to our `mongoose` models, let's call it `app/models`.

We have one repo for the backend and one for the admin, written in Angular 2. When attempting to share the models definition between the 2, angular complains about `mongoose.model` not being being a function. As a small example, this is how we placed the files

```
backend
    api
        get_blog_posts.ts

angular2
    post-editor.ts

app/models
    index.ts
    /schemas
        blog_post.ts
    /models
        blog_posts.ts
```

`/schemas/blog_posts.ts` exports an interface which we want to use in our `Angular 2` app

```
export interface BlogPostSchema {...}
```

`/models/blog_posts.ts` exports `BlogPostModel` which is a basic `mongoose` model like so:

```
import {BlogPostSchema} from '../schemas/blog_post'

const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({...})
export const BlogPostModel = mongoose.model<BlogPostSchema>('BlogPost', Schema, 'blog_posts')
```

`index.ts` exports these 2:

```
export {BlogPostSchema} from './schemas/blog_posts'
export {BlogPostModel} from './models/blog_posts'
```

And in out Angular 2 app, we consume the `BlogPostSchema` like so:

```
import {BlogPostSchema} from 'app/models' // app/models is installed as an npm module

@Component({...})
export class BlogPostEditorComponent {

    postItems: BlogPostSchema[];
}
```

When attempting the same on our backend app, everything works perfectly, however, in our Angular 2 built using `angular/cli`, we get the error:

```
TypeError: mongoose.model is not a function
at Object.Array.concat.Object.defineProperty.value (blog_post.ts?58c8*:70)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b8ea1f1…:52)
at Object.Array.concat.Object.defineProperty.value (index.ts?adf0*:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b8ea1f1…:52)
at Object.Array.concat.webpackEmptyContext.keys (index.ts?f9f5*:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b8ea1f1…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.ts:22)
```

We don't want to use the `BlogPostModel` in our Angular 2 app, we only need the interface `BlogPostSchema`.

Note that the server and the `app/models` module was written in `TypeScript`. Among the settings when compiling the module, these two are - I think - the most important fields:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution about how to share models/contracts between node and angular 2 projects?

Comment: @galvan we ended up splitting the interfaces and models into 2 separate modules. We had to avoid using the models inside Angular that has any reference to `mongoose` or any other modules that is `Node.js` specific. Instead of importing the models, we only imported the interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so if I understand correctly you have dependency on these two modules in both node and angular projects. What about the dev process? on each model/contract change you than update the module version and installing the module again with npm/yarn?

Comment: @galvan you should read about the `npm link` command. This allows you to develop and use a module locally without having to re-install that module every time you make changes.